# Power BI: change measure value based on parameter input and slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, reporting, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am working on a report where I need to change the value of a measure, let's say measure A, based on the parameter value, but only for the country selected in the slicer.

So I have this table visual that shows continents, countries, flags and a lot of measures. All of the data comes from the source name "DATA", besides the flag which is coming from a custom table I made that stores country names and flag links.

Then I created this parameter, "Param" and the Country filter which is based on the name of the countries from the Country table.

I changed the "A" measure formula to add the parameter to it when the country is filtered, but only for the country that is filtered.

```
A = IF(ISFILTERED(Countries[Country]),[B] - [C] - [D] + 'Param'[Param Value], [B] - [C] - [D])
```

When I change the value of the parameter and apply a country filter the measure A is calculated correct for the country selected, but for the others all the values of the measures in the table dissapear.

Do you have any idea what I can do to make change only the A measure of the country selected in the filter without changing the values for the other countries at all?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a personal consulting service: You should not post your business problems here. 
Instead, reduce the problem to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and make the question more generic, so that others can learn from it as well. 
And please add sample data in [copyable text format](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this forumla might get what you actually need.

easue= Switch ( True(),

if(condition1,"Result1" ,

if(condition1,"Result1"  ,
etc... )

And for the slicer this link actually explains how to use it.

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-bi-measure-switch/

Comment: The reason you use `SWITCH` is specifically to avoid nested `IF` statements in your code. Why have both?

Comment: @Pushkin In %99.99999 of my DAX codes, I have never seen the usage of both of SWITCH & IF in the same structure. Please omit those redundant if's, and restructure your switch statement.